# How to find people who +1 my comment?

Tags: google-plus, comments

Anyone knows how can I find the full name of a person who +1'd my comment? 
I get a notification of several people who +1'd it recently, but I can only see all of them in a small square and their first names. And there's no way of opening their URL's by clicking on their names or pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you view the full post page, there comment +1'ers list has full names and link to the users profiles.

[image]